Spring Cloud Config Server to serve even when its git backend is down
I have a config service running on GKE using Git backend. I want to make it can serve even when Git is down. Currently it already can serve when Git is down because it checks out everything into its local filesystem and use those to serve. But if during that time the config service itself restarts, it cannot perform the initial clone.
I tried using a persistence disk which the data is still there when config service restarts, but the thing is, the first thing of Git clone is to clear the working directory no matter whether clone is successful. Which makes "persistence" meaningless.
Any thought on how to make this done?

You can populate the according directory with an initcontainer for the code you check out with a sidecar periodically saving the config to a volume from which the initcontainer reads. That being said, it is a Very Bad Idea™: The path the backend checks the code out in is not documented and as such subject to change, potentially breaking your config and by its very nature defying the idea of the cloud config server altogether  to decouple config and applications. With what you describe, this sounds much more like a job for the vault backend.

After further test, the initial clean-up only happens when cloneOnStart is enabled, or it will try to use the existing repo first. So I can still store the config-repo into an external persistence disk. I think this approach meets the requirement. Thank you anyway.

I couldn't figure out how to close this question, just leave it there maybe.

You can answer your own question... ;) Totally valid solution.
